# Create javascript array of arrays from string (which contains strings)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following string

```
['Value',2],['Value2',4],['Value3',10]
```

I would like to convert this to javascript array.  I should be able to

```
var tmpStrings = "['Value',2],['Value2',4],['Value3',10]";     
var arrStrings = JSON.parse("[" + tmpStrings + "]");
```

Unfortunately I get unexpected character errors.  I thought that it might be the single quotes but escaping them doesn't change anything.  Int seems to work fine, the below runs for me fine

```
var tmpInts = "[4,2],[5,3],[6,3]"; 
var arrInts = JSON.parse("[" + tmpInts + "]");
```

Comment: Can you show the expected result. It's not 100% clear that you want an array of arrays, though I suspect you do.

Comment: single quotes aren't valid JSON is why it is failing

Comment: You can invert it `var tmpStrings = '["Value",2],["Value2",4],["Value3",10]';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON will not accept `'`. So, you need to change that to double quotes, like this

```
console.log(JSON.parse("[" + tmpStrings.replace(/'/g, '"') + "]"));
# [ [ 'Value', 2 ], [ 'Value2', 4 ], [ 'Value3', 10 ] ]
```

We are just replacing all the `'` in the string to double quotes.

**Warning:** This would replace `'` with `"`, even if it appears in the middle of the string.